# Odd behavior in Explicit Expand with inherited models in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I've been trying to get a real response from AutoMapper from 2.5 years about this issue. I'm using `ProjectTo` feature with *Explicit Expand* and it does not work properly when using inherited mapped classes.
Here is the plug-and-play test (also available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/JobaDiniz/628ceda9133843fad447152f1b9e8cc9)), just add it to the AutoMapper test project, run it and you'll see that they do not pass.

```
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;

namespace AutoMapper.UnitTests.Bug
{
    public class ExplicitExpansionWithIncludeBase
    {
        /*********** Source Types ***********/
        abstract class EntityBase
        {
            public EntityBase() => Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        }

        class User { }
        class Computer : EntityBase { }
        class Script : EntityBase
        {
            public Computer Computer { get; set; }
        }

        /*********** Destination Types ***********/
        class EntityBaseModel
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public UserModel CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public UserModel ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        }

        class UserModel { }
        class ComputerModel : EntityBaseModel { }
        class ScriptModel : EntityBaseModel
        {
            public ComputerModel Computer { get; set; }
        }

        private IConfigurationProvider BuildConfiguration()
        {
            return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
                cfg.CreateMap<EntityBase, EntityBaseModel>()
                .MaxDepth(1)
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
                cfg.CreateMap<Computer, ComputerModel>()
                .MaxDepth(1)
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
                cfg.CreateMap<Script, ScriptModel>()
                .MaxDepth(1)
                .ForMember(d => d.Computer, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
            });
        }

        private Script CreateModel()
        {
            var computer = new Computer()
            {
                CreatedBy = new User(),
                ModifiedBy = new User(),
            };
            return new Script()
            {
                CreatedBy = new User(),
                ModifiedBy = new User(),
                Computer = computer
            };
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ComputerCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand_when_using_expressions()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, c => c.Computer, c => c.CreatedBy).Single(); // Expand Computer and CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.Computer.CreatedBy); //Not Explicit call to 'expand'
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ComputerCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer", "CreatedBy").Single(); // Expand Computer and CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.Computer.CreatedBy); //CreatedBy from Computer was not specified in 'membersToExpand'
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ComputerCreatedBy_shouldnt_be_null_BUT_ScriptCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer.CreatedBy").Single(); // Expand Computer.CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.NotNull(scriptModel.Computer.CreatedBy);
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.CreatedBy); //CreatedBy from Script was not specified in 'membersToExpand'
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ScriptCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer.CreatedBy").Single(); // Expand Computer.CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.CreatedBy); //CreatedBy from Script was not specified in 'membersToExpand'
        }
    }

    public class ExplicitExpansionWithIncludeBaseUsingNewKeyword
    {
        /*********** Source Types ***********/
        abstract class EntityBase
        {
            public EntityBase() => Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        }

        class User { }
        class Computer : EntityBase { }
        class Script : EntityBase
        {
            public Computer Computer { get; set; }
        }

        /*********** Destination Types ***********/
        class EntityBaseModel
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public UserModel CreatedBy { get; set; }
            public UserModel ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        }

        class UserModel { }
        class ComputerModel : EntityBaseModel
        {
            public new UserModel CreatedBy { get; set; } //NOTE: the 'new' keyword here make the tests pass
        }
        class ScriptModel : EntityBaseModel
        {
            public new UserModel CreatedBy { get; set; } //NOTE: the 'new' keyword here make the tests pass
            public ComputerModel Computer { get; set; }
        }

        private IConfigurationProvider BuildConfiguration()
        {
            return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
                cfg.CreateMap<EntityBase, EntityBaseModel>()
                .MaxDepth(1)
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
                cfg.CreateMap<Computer, ComputerModel>()
                .MaxDepth(1)
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
                cfg.CreateMap<Script, ScriptModel>()
                .MaxDepth(1)
                .ForMember(d => d.Computer, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.ModifiedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion())
                .ForMember(d => d.CreatedBy, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
            });
        }

        private Script CreateModel()
        {
            var computer = new Computer()
            {
                CreatedBy = new User(),
                ModifiedBy = new User(),
            };
            return new Script()
            {
                CreatedBy = new User(),
                ModifiedBy = new User(),
                Computer = computer
            };
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ComputerCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand_when_using_expressions()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, c => c.Computer, c => c.CreatedBy).Single(); // Expand Computer and CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.Computer.CreatedBy); //Not Explicit call to 'expand'
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ComputerCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer", "CreatedBy").Single(); // Expand Computer and CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.Computer.CreatedBy); //CreatedBy from Computer was not specified in 'membersToExpand'
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ComputerCreatedBy_shouldnt_be_null_BUT_ScriptCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer.CreatedBy").Single(); // Expand Computer.CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.NotNull(scriptModel.Computer.CreatedBy);
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.CreatedBy); //CreatedBy from Script was not specified in 'membersToExpand'
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ScriptCreatedBy_should_be_null_because_it_was_not_specified_in_members_to_expand()
        {
            // arrange
            var config = BuildConfiguration();
            var script = CreateModel();

            // act
            var scriptModel = new[] { script }.AsQueryable()
                .ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer.CreatedBy").Single(); // Expand Computer.CreatedBy from Script

            // assert
            Assert.Null(scriptModel.CreatedBy); //CreatedBy from Script was not specified in 'membersToExpand'
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 test classes in the gist. The `ExplicitExpansionWithIncludeBase` explores the **bug**. The `ExplicitExpansionWithIncludeBaseUsingNewKeyword` shows that using the `new` **keyword** in the properties of inherited classes makes the tests pass, which is odd.

For example, `ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, c => c.Computer, c => c.CreatedBy)` should fetch `Computer` and `CreatedBy` properties of **only** `Script`, but it also fetches `Computer.CreatedBy` property.
Similarly, `ProjectTo<ScriptModel>(config, null, "Computer.CreatedBy")` should fetch **only** `Computer.CreatedBy` but it also fetches `Script.CreatedBy` property.

It seems that AutoMapper expands members regardless their depth in the object graph, which I strongly believe it's a **bug**.

Comment: This seems more like a bug report, rather than a question, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: well, I tried to report this bug (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3422) and they told me to open stackoverflow, so here I am, and now I should open a bug? :(

Comment: I believe they were wrong in sending you here. After re-reading the question (multiple times) I can't see how this is a question (a good indicator for a question is normally a question mark, and I don't see any). I urge you to pick this up again with the folks from AutoMapper by leaving a comment explaining why you don't think its a question and asking for feedback why they think it is

Comment: Thanks, I've done that, but the comment was deleted and issue closed. Now someone answered there.